# How to limit/filter source columns of a CSV file while importing to Azure data factory

Tags: azure

I have a 20 GB `.CSV` file with 300 columns, but I don't want all those 300 columns, I just need 30 of those columns. How can I restrict the unwanted columns to ADF?

Or can I re-frame my question: how to import only specific columns of a .CSV file

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, as written, your question is off-topic (very broad, and a bit like a documentation/example request). Please edit your question to show what you've done so far, where where, specifically, you're having issues. How are you reading data with ADF: Copy Activity? If so: how have you set it up? Note: ADF docs have plenty of material that walks through working with input schemas; I would start there.

Answer (score 0):

In the copy activity, click on the mapping tab and then click on import schemas. You should be able to see all the columns from your source csv. You can then select the ones you don't need and click on delete.

On doing this, only the columns which left in the mapping will get copied over. See attached screen shot.[image]

Comment: Thank you Chand ...we can filter run-wanted in copy activity ..but can we do it a data flow ,I have 2 files of 30 GB and 20 GB with 274 columns each  ,and joining the primary key  of both CSV files and pulling only 28 columns out of it ....so I want to restrict those unwanted coloums while importing source itself instead of at sink level